# What does google-closure-compiler -O BUNDLE do?

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure

I think that the `-O BUNDLE` option to `google-closure-compiler` might collect my JS scripts into a single file in order to perform better optimization of the code across files and scopes. HOWEVER, I cannot find any documentation on the option other than that it exists.

Does anyone know what this option does?